# CCRenderTexture Scheduler Performance

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, textures

I'm looking for a best practice for my issue.  I created a CCRenderTexture that's a black background with a hole Sprite to give a game a Spotlight effect.  The spotlight follows the main character around as if they are in a dark room with a candle.  My issue is that, when I run the below code in the scheduling method, my CPU usage jumps from 19% to 65% on an iPhone 5 in debug mode.  To me, this feels like I'm implementing this strategy incorrectly.  This this the correct way to "refresh" a texture in the scheduling method?  I am using Cocos2D 3.1.

```
- (void)update:(CCTime)delta
{
    self.spotlight.position = pt;  
    [self.renderLayer beginWithClear:0.0f g:0.0f b:0.0f a:1.0f];
    [self.spotlight visit];
    [self.renderLayer end];
}
```

Comment: On any performance related question, please state in detail the run environment ... sim, device, debug vs release, etc

Comment: Sorry, it's on an iPhone 5 device in debug mode.